# OS X Screen Share @ light-blue screen; can't login

Tags: mac-osx, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I was screen sharing to a OS X 10.5.8 Server and hit Log Out. From there, it went to a light-blue screen with a black mouse pointer, and now I can't log back in! How do I get back on to Screen Share without having to reboot the server? It's a file server and all of the files are still accessible, so the server is definitely still up and running, just can't screen share.

Comment: Have you tried killing Remote Desktop? `killall ARDAgent` -- Or maybe even the WindowServer? `sudo killall -HUP WindowServer`?

Comment: No luck @jscott

Answer (score 1):

Can you log into it via ssh and check the running processes? There should be a screen share process or something of that nature that you can then kill -9.

Might be something in the logs under /var/log that can give a clue as well.